# Best way to save form input in flutter as the user types in

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, dart, input

This is an open question for the best practices and experiences with creating forms in flutter.
I didn't find a lot of material online, other than basic username and password form.

I was trying to create a screen in flutter that receives user input which is `String` and `double` inputs (32 inputs). I have to validate data to make sure numbers are within range, then do calculations and create a detailed PDF report.

My plan was to create a class say `InputData` where I can store all user inputs, and in my `inputScreen` create a `Form` widget with `TextFormField`s to receive and validate inputs

```
Expanded MyCustomTextFormField(String labelText, TextInputType textInputType) {
  return Expanded(
        child: TextFormField(
          keyboardType: textInputType,
          maxLines: 2,
          minLines: 1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: labelText,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

How can I store all input data in one `InputData` class I created as the user types in, and how would I store it on the phone as the user types as well.

Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using textEditingController?

Comment: It would be so difficult to add textEditingController to 32 fields, is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you have any example? Or any ideas on how to apply this to all 32 fields .. documentation is not so clear for me and this form has taken a lot of effort, initially I thought flutter was easier and quicker but after this form it’s longer